# BrokeredMessage send and Message consumer in Azure Function v2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have mock azure web jobs, which periodically push `BrokeredMessage` to the service bus topic, like this

```
public void Simulate(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */30 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]
            TimerInfo timerInfo,
            [ServiceBus("%topic%")]
            out BrokeredMessage message)
        {
            message = new BrokeredMessage(
                new AwesomeContract()
                {

                });
        }
```

In azure function V2, I am trying to consume it using `Message` class.

```
public static void Integrate(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(
                "%topic%",
                "%subscribtion%",
                Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] Message message,
            TraceWriter log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
              message.GetBody<AwesomeContract>();
            }
        }
```

On `GetBody<>` I receive `DataContractSerialization` exception "*There was an error deserializing the object of type . The input source is not correctly formatted.*"

Are `BrokeredMessage` and `Message` compatible in azure function v1 and v2? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

`BrokeredMessage` is the message object from the library WindowsAzure.ServiceBus, where `Message` is the object from the library Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.

Even though the object type differs between these libraries, sending the message body as a `Stream` will help in overcoming the exception while reading the body.

```
message = new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([message_body]));
```

Constructing the message as above will help.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Same error

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the following interop class while attempting to find help for a similar issue: [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Extensions.MessageInterOpExtensions.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Extensions/MessageInterOpExtensions.cs)
*note: the examples in the documentation all assumes that you have access to the messagereceiver, which being in an Azure Function you most likely do not.*

According to the comment there, your particular configuration *should* work, but apparently there is some unknown error there - you may have to roll your own extension, or see if you can use the *message.Body byte[]* property

The BrokeredMessage constructor for custom objects says that it is using DataContractSerializer with a binary XmlDictionaryWriter, so if we know what the *Content-Type* is, we may be able to see why the DataContractSerializer fails.

If all else fails, or untill this apparent bug is fixed, you may have to see if you can use the byte array in the *Body* property and roll your own serializer/extension method.

Comment: The package Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is marked as deprecated now